# Linear operator convergence in $L_2(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Assume a sequence of operators $A_n:L_2(\mathbb{R})→L_2(\mathbb{R}), n\in \mathbb{N}$, with the following expression:

$$A_nx(t)=e^{−(t−n)^2}x(t)$$

I'm trying to analyze its convergence, starting from the uniform convergence through

$$\|A_n - A_m \| = \sup_{\|x\| \leq 1} \|A_nx - A_mx \| = \sup_{\|x\| \leq 1} \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|e^{-(t-n)^2}x(t) - e^{-(t-m)^2} x(t)\right|^{2}dt \right)^{1/2} = \sup_{\|x\| \leq 1} \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}}x^2(t)\left[e^{-(t-n)^2} - e^{-(t-m)^2}\right]^2 dt \right)^{1/2}$$

However, I'm not sure what's the proper way to tackle the exponents in order to find a bound and see whether it converges. Drilling down and expanding the powers didn't seem to result in an obvious solution.

Would appreciate any hints or observations!

Comment: When you look at $||A_n-A_m||$ you're looking at _norm_ convergence, sometimes called "uniform" convergence. That's stronger than strong convergence. In fact these operators do _not_ converge in norm. They do converge strongly to $0$; that means $||A_nx||\to0$ for every $x$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich thanks for your observation, I'm studying this in my native language and was not sure about the proper naming; uniform convergence however does seem in line with my notes, will edit the question. 
Secondly, what's the main evidence here that suggests that these operators do not converge in norm? Or in general -- what's the strategy to get a better feel whether the operator sequence actually doesn't converge, or, i.e., the bound was just too large and some trick/observation might be missing. which would reduce the bound?

Comment: If $T:L^2\to L^2$ is a multiplication operator, $Tf(x)=m(x)f(x)$, then it's not hard to show that $||T||=||m||_\infty$ (assuming, say, that the measure is $\sigma$-finite). Hence  for fixed $n$  we have $\lim_{m\to\infty}||A_n-A_m||=1$, so $(A_n)$ is not Cauchy in norm.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich could you please expand on how does the $\lim=1$ part follow from the preceding observation?

Comment: No. Draw a picture of $e^{-(n-t)^2}-e^{-(m-t)^2}$ for $m>>n$;  what is  the sup norm,  approximately?

Comment: Or: Say $e_n(t)=e^{-(t-n)^2}$. Two hints: (i) if $\alpha,\beta\in[0,1]$ then $|\alpha-\beta|\le1$, (ii) $||e_n-e_m||_\infty\ge|e_n(m)-e_m(m)|$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich do I understand correctly, that we get the main result from  $\sup_{\|x\|≤1}(\int_{\mathbb{R}}x^2(t) [ e_n(t) - e_m(t)]^2dt)^{1/2} \leq \sup_{\|x\|≤1} \| x \| \| e_n - e_m \|_{\infty} = 1$?

Comment: Yes. More or less - of course that last "$=1$" isn't quite right...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Thanks! However, how do we know whether the sup norm bound on the $|e_n−e_m|$ isn't too strict and that there doesn't exist a weaker bound, which would allow for norm convergence to 0? Or does this follow from the fact that $\|T\|=\|m\|_{\infty}$, as you have mentioned earlier?

Comment: Yes, $||A_n-A_m||=||e_n-e_m||_\infty.$ Say $Tf(x)=m(x)f(x)$. It's trivial that $||T||\le||m||_\infty$. It's an easy exercise to show that if $\alpha<||m||_\infty$ then there exists $f\ne0$ with $||Tf||\ge\alpha||f||$. Hint: This uses the _definition_ of $||m||_\infty$ - it's not quite the sup.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Thank you, your comments really helped a lot! Last quick question: for strong convergence, how do we see that $\|A_nx\| \rightarrow 0$? Does this follow from the fact that $e^{-(t-n)^2} \rightarrow 0, n \rightarrow \infty$ for fixed $t$? If so, why weren't we able to take the same limit for norm convergence?

Comment: Try dominated convergence.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich perfect. For the last part, since $\|A_n\| = \|e_n\|_{\infty}, \forall n$, we can find such $x_0$ that $\|A_n x_0\| \geq \|e_n\|_{\infty} \|x_0\|$, yet strong convergence implies $\|A_n x \| \rightarrow 0$ for all $x$. If we can find such $x_0$ for every $n$, it intuitively seems that some maximum of all such $x_0$ would contradict strong convergence.. I feel I am missing something, but can't grasp on what? Now thinking about it, I guess I'll try looking for proofs why norm convergence is stronger than strong.

Comment: Probably better to call it $x_n$, since it depends on $n$. If you mean the pointwise maximum as $L^2$ functions, there's no reason that should be in $L^2$.